# TV Screen disconnect when playing sound over hdmi

Tags: 12.10, pulseaudio, hdmi

I just spent hours to configure the sound to work with HDMI.
My last problem is, when I start playing sound the TV screen goes on and off, like when you change the resolution. When I stop playing sound, 3-5 seconds after, the same thing happen.
I feel like everytime I play/stop the sound, the HDMI connection needs to be resetted. Really annoying!

To enable the sound over HDMI, I have done :

```
pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo
```

Which basically set the pulse audio profile to HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your sound hardware you may also find the appropriate port to where your digital HDMI sound goes. To list ports of cards available issue:

```
pacmd list-cards
```

Usually there are several profiles available to adress different ports. These will also be lsited with the command above. Try if selecting another profile gives you the expected results (replace `<card-index>` and `<profile-name>` with values read above):

```
pacmd set-card-profile <card-index> <profile-name>
```

If no profiles adressing different ports are available you can also change the port of a given sink with:

```
pacmd list-sinks  # to read the sink index for the next command
pcmad set-sink-port <sink-index> <port-name>
```

---

In case you have a graphical desktop you may also change the card profile with [**pavucontrol**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol) [image: Install pavucontrol] in the *"Configuration"* tab:

[image]

<sup>Note that different HDMI-profiles may be listed which all show up having the same name.</sup>

---

If all that fails you may try to disable [HDMI-CEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#CEC) on your TV set or try with a different HDMI cable as flickering of the screen on your TV set may indicate an erroneous electrical input on the HDMI-ports.